# Traversing to child object dynamically

Tags: c#

I had a parent object and want to traverse to the child object dynamically.

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
        this.MyProperty1 = new List<Class2>();
    }

    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public List<Class2> MyProperty1 { get; set; }
}
class Class2
{
    public Class2()
    {
        this.MyProperty2 = new List<Class3>();
    }

    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public List<Class3> MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
class Class3
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

}
```

if i need to read myproperty in class3 i need to do somthing like

```
Class1.MyProperty1.Last().MyProperty2.Last().MyProperty
```

which i want to do dynamically using reflections

Please Help

Comment: You can probably achieve this using reflection but the question is why? What's the problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Why reflection? Why you need something else at all? Your current code should work already.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: i was actually trying to make this dynamic  which will take input as parent object and the child object name and traverse to the child and the object is  nested so i need to write a lot of code for each traversal

Comment: There are so many reasons why this is such a bad idea.

Comment: @jhon can you tell in detail why it is a bad idea

Comment: @HoaxGod: if you'd use a reflection approach that would be very prone to errors. You would use this method only for this case. Then better avoid reflection. Makes your code also more efficient, compile time safe and more readable

Comment: still is there a way to do that if so please help me

Comment: may be a better description of the problem would help. Why exactly do you access only the last item in `MyProperty1` and `MyProperty2`? Do you want to use reflection because you have a similar structure in `Class1` and `Class2` ?

Comment: i am trying to push the child object data and that needs to be pushed into the last and the structure is diffrent for class 1 and 2

Comment: up to now your `MyProperty2` list can only contain a certain type. Do you want that it can contain other types than `Class3`/Child?

Comment: yes it will be having multiple child object but there are no child objects with 2 parents so checking for the parent level should not be an issue for now

Comment: @HoaxGod 1) It will be slow, especially when you start drilling down lists. Imagine you have 10 lists in Class1, each has 100 items, which each contain lists. Compare that to just going for the element you want. 2) How will you handle objects like dictionaries? What would a key be in your world? 3) What if you have two child objects with the same name in two classes? Which one do you choose? 4) You'll have to write code to handle strange cases that pop up and exceptions to the logic will grow exponentially.

Comment: i was planing to go bottom up approach  and the child object is going to have  a single parent and the class names are unique so there will be only one traverse path  so comparing wont be a problem so is ter any possible way

Comment: So you want to start at the child and find a parent of a specific type? Why not just implement a "Parent()" method in each class that links to its parent?

Comment: i want to do the bottom up approach so that i can find the path for that class but if i want to do something like to push data into the child object that changes it is not possible by just using a parent method                                               i want to create a method more or less like                                                public A adddata(A a,string ChildClassname,object ChildObject){
//Logic to push data to that particular Child Object
}
so in order to get the correct traverse path i want to go through bottom up approach with out much searching

Comment: @HoaxGod What are you doing this for? As a former colleague would say: this smells like bad meat. It sounds like you need to rethink your design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public List<string> ChildPath(string ChildObject, List<string> ParentNameList, string AssembleyPath, string NameSpace, List<string> TraversedNodes)
    {
        Type ChildType = Type.GetType(NameSpace + ChildObject + AssembleyPath);
        List<string> Properties = ChildType.GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType.IsClass && x.PropertyType.Assembly.GetName().Name != "mscorlib").Select(x => x.Name).ToList();

        ParentNameList.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ChildObject].ToString());           
       // List<string> Properties = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Child_" + ChildObject].ToString().Split(',').ToList();
        int MaxIndex = 0;
        ChildObject = null;
        foreach (string item in Properties)
        {
            int PresIndex = TraversedNodes.IndexOf(item);
            if (MaxIndex <= PresIndex)
            {
                MaxIndex = PresIndex;
                ChildObject = item;
            }
        }
        if (ChildObject != null)
            PathTravarse(ChildObject, ParentNameList, AssembleyPath, NameSpace, TraversedNodes);
        return ParentNameList;
    }  


public object GetLastChild(object DataObject, List<string> Path)
    {

        object Destination = DataObject;
        int Count = Path.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            PropertyInfo ChildProperty = Destination.GetType().GetProperty(Path[i]);
            Destination = ChildProperty.GetValue(Destination, null);
            Destination = ((IList)Destination)[((IList)Destination).Count - 1];               
        }

        return Destination;

    }

         public object CreateChildInstance(object DataObject, List<string> Path, string ChildName,string AssembleyPath,string NameSpace)
    {

        object Destination = DataObject;
        int Count = Path.Count - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            PropertyInfo ChildProperty = Destination.GetType().GetProperty(Path[i]);
            Destination = ((IList)ChildProperty.GetValue(Destination, null));
            Destination = ((IList)Destination)[((IList)Destination).Count - 1];
        }
        PropertyInfo FinalChild = Destination.GetType().GetProperty(Path[Count]);
        Destination = FinalChild.GetValue(Destination, null);
        Type InstanceType = Type.GetType(NameSpace + ChildName + AssembleyPath);
        Destination.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(Destination, new[] { Activator.CreateInstance(InstanceType) });
        return DataObject;

    }
```